# why the PayPal buttons are not rendering?

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal

i am trying to add the PayPal smarts buttons into my angular app , [here is the link of the PayPal instruction how to add](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/#try-the-buttons)

i have already tried the to add script in my angular component .

```
 ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
        if (!this.addScript) {
        this.addPaypalScript().then(() => {
        console.log('paypal',paypal)
        paypal.Buttons({

          // Set up the transaction
          createOrder: function(data, actions) {
              return actions.order.create({
                  purchase_units: [{
                      amount: {
                          value: '0.01'
                      }
                  }]
              });
          },

          // Finalize the transaction
          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
              return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                  // Show a success message to the buyer
                  alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
              });
          }


      }, '#paypal-checkout-btn');
        this.addScript = true;
      })
    }
  }
addPaypalScript() {
    this.addScript = true;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let scripttagElement = document.createElement('script');    
      scripttagElement.src = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb';
      scripttagElement.onload = resolve;
      document.body.appendChild(scripttagElement);
    })
  }

`

its not showing any thing
```

Comment: where are you rendering the button ?

Comment: @BernardPagoaga here in component html file 
 `<div id="paypal-checkout-btn" >     </div>`

Comment: I think you are supposed to use the render method of the Button object : `<script>paypal.Buttons().render('body');</script>`

Comment: @BernardPagoaga thank you so much 